# How do I roll a random number once to be used on multiple classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner C# programmer in general, attempting to create a Japanese falling word typing game in Unity where the word / letter shown on screen will be in Hiragana, but the requested input is in Romaji (alphabetical) letters.

Currently, I am stuck in a rut attempting to figure out how to generate a random number once per words.Add (word) is executed. For instance, when a Word object is created, generate a random number. Then, that random number is used on classes that depend on it, such as getWord_Hiragana, and getWord_Romaji. Most typing games existing on the internet are shown only a single object (English), so I couldn't find what I need.

```
// WordManager.cs
public class WordManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Word> words;

    public WordSpawner wordSpawner;

    public void AddWord ()
    {
        Word word = new Word (WordGenerator.GetWord_Romaji(), wordSpawner.SpawnWord());

        words.Add (word);
    }
}
```

```
// WordGenerator.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class WordGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public static string[] wordList_Hiragana = {    "あ", "い", "う", "え", "お" };

    public static string[] wordList_Katakana = {    "ア", "イ", "ウ", "エ", "オ" };

    public static string[] wordList_Romaji = {      "a", "i", "u", "e", "o" };

    public static int GetIndex ()
    {
        int index = Random.Range (0, wordList_Romaji.Length - 1);   // Get Random number which has the same index for Hiragana, Katakana, and Romaji arrays

        Debug.Log ("Index #" + index + ": " + wordList_Hiragana[index] + " " + wordList_Katakana[index] + " " + wordList_Romaji[index]); // Debug Log

        return index; // Returns the result of the random as a guidance.
    }


    public static string GetWord_Hiragana ()    // A function to return the result of GetIndex as Hiragana word to be used on WordManager and in turn, displays that Hiragana.
    {
        int index = GetIndex ();

        string getWord_Hiragana = wordList_Hiragana [index];
        return getWord_Hiragana;
    }

    public static string GetWord_Romaji ()  
    {
        int index = GetIndex ();
        string getWord_Romaji = wordList_Romaji [index];

        return getWord_Romaji;
    }
}
```

```
// Word.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Word {

    public string word;
    private int typeIndex; // Checks for current letter

    WordDisplay display;

    public Word (string _word, WordDisplay _display)  // Displays the word as Hiragana / Katakana
    {
        word = _word;

        display = _display;
        display.SetWord (word);
    }

    public char GetNextLetter ()
    {
        return word[typeIndex]; // Gets the next letter of the Romaji array
    }

    public void TypeLetter ()
    {
        typeIndex++;
    }

    public bool WordTyped ()
    {
        bool wordTyped = (typeIndex >= word.Length); // Checks if the whole word has been typed
        if (wordTyped) 
        {
            display.RemoveWord (); // Remove the whole object on screen
        }
        return wordTyped;
    }
}
```

The expected result is for GetIndex to roll a random number **once** per Word object. When getWord_Romaji is executed, it grabs the return value of GetIndex. The same goes when getWord_Hiragana is executed. Right now, GetIndex is executed twice and generates a random number twice in each Word object, causing the word that appeared on Debug to be different compared to what appears on the game screen. How do I make this work?

If the code above is not enough to solve the problem, the project is posted [here](https://github.com/Xierra/JapaneseFallingTypingGame).

Comment: I answered this in a prior comment on, what I assume, is a now-deleted duplicate question. `GetWord_Xxxx(int index)`. Stop re-randomizing every time you call a `GetWord` function and instead randomize ONCE and pass that value into each get method.

Comment: I would introduce a `Word` class, with a non-static field storing the index, and I would compute the random index  at the constructor. Of course you would need some way to store and manage your `Word` object instances.

Comment: Totally agree with @BlueStrat.  You need to store the **state** (random index) of the Word in an instance class.  Static functions can't return something on a "per instance" basics, which is what you're asking for...

Comment: @Draco18s I'm not sure if this duplicate question was mine, but I did delete a question actually has no mistakes recently. Whoops. I need a deeper explanation on how to pass a value to each get method.

Comment: @XierraMarron If it wasn't yours, it was basically the same code. Same Japanese characters, same GetWord functions, everything. I can't find it now, which is why I suspect it was deleted (while I can *view* deleted questions at my rep, I can't *search* for them).

Comment: @Draco18s I checked the deleted question. The question I deleted has the exact same code, actually, but the question itself is a flub, because what Foggzie said was right, the code does work properly, it's only a matter of calling it. And yes, you were there. it's a different question this time, though. :)

Comment: Can you show us class `Word`?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sure. Do note that you can look at the whole project on the link below.

Comment: @XierraMarron Sounds good. I couldn't be sure the *question* was the same, but the code was memorable. No worries about what you did from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your `Word` class constructor to the below:

```
public class Word
{

    public string word;
    private int typeIndex; // Checks for current letter

    private int wordIndex; // index of word used from WordGenerator

    WordDisplay display;

    public Word(WordDisplay _display)  // Displays the word as Hiragana / Katakana
    {
        wordIndex = WordGenerator.GetIndex(); // now it will only be called ONCE per instance
        word = _WordGenerator.wordList_Romaji[wordIndex];

        // you can get the equivalent? letters similarly...with something like:
        word = _WordGenerator.wordList_Hiragana[wordIndex];

        display = _display;
        display.SetWord(word);
    }

    // ... other existing code ...

}
```

Note that I've added another field to store the index selected for that particular word instance.

Comment: That's a great idea! (although I have to remove the _ from WordGenerator to avoid compiler errors), and I managed to make it work. By changing the two word vars into romaji var and hiragana var respectively, and then changing to display.SetWord(hiragana) while the existing code below changed into romaji, it now works as intended (type the romaji of the hiragana that appears on screen). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the implementation of `Word` I'ld say from your example it actually **does** call `GetIndex()` only exactly once ... namely for `GetWord_Romaji()` ...

Anyway a quick simple fix could be

```
private static int randomizedIndex;

public static void NewRandomIndex()
{
    randomizedIndex = Random.Range (0, wordList_Romaji.Length - 1);

    Debug.Log("Index #" + randomizedIndex + ": " + wordList_Hiragana[randomizedIndex] + " " + wordList_Katakana[randomizedIndex] + " " + wordList_Romaji[randomizedIndex]);
}

public static string GetWord_Hiragana()
{
    return wordList_Hiragana[randomizedIndex];
}

public static string GetWord_Romaji ()  
{
    return wordList_Romaji[randomizedIndex];
}
```

and call it

```
public void AddWord ()
{
    WordGenerator.NewRandomIndex();

    Word word = new Word(WordGenerator.GetWord_Romaji(), wordSpawner.SpawnWord());
    words.Add (word);
}
```

---

If you rather want to be able to later "translate" the words between those arrays then you should in `Word` instead of retrieved `string` rather store the used `randomizedIndex` and get the `string` value for it "on the fly".

Comment: I just realized I interpreted the GetWord_Hiragana wrongly, whoops. Anyway, I tried using this code, but then every index should be called randomizedIndex. Also, I would have solved this code myself if that worked, because it doesn't. Creating the GetWord_Hiragana and GetWord_Romaji that way would make it not exist in current context. Also, I had to call the index function because I cannot convert method group to non-delegate type "string", so I added the parentheses (randomizedIndex()) for it, forcing the re-randomize. Hence why I'm stuck in a rut.